# CORS policy access issue with Chatbot in sdk v4 C# .Net Core

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, chatbot

I have a chatbot that is developed using `sdk v4` in `.Net Core`. I deployed the bot on Azure and it was working perfectly. By the end of the day I interacted again with it and I started getting the following error:

> One or more errors occurred. (Operation returned an invalid status code ‘Forbidden’)

and in my browser console I saw this:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://botservice.hosting.portal.azure.net/botservice/api/ClientTrace' from origin 'https://portal.azure.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Is there anything I am missing? Why did it started happening out of the blue? What is the reason and ramification?

Comment: Try  this to see if could solve your issue or not : go to your bot service => "all app service settings" =>CORS => adding "*" as a record to enable all js requests to call your bot . This post will be helpful : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/5bd37aa7-eed7-4ddd-a560-c36a09e1674d/how-can-i-enable-the-cors-on-my-app-hosted-on-azure-portal?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: I tried. Still getting the same error.

Comment: What client are you using to talk with the bot? If it's WebChat, where is it hosted? Can you provide your appId so I can look into this on the back end?

Comment: I am using webchat, both directline and Iframe for this. here is the app id:fdb223ef-cbe6-4175-a557-2f4d9cf5e649.

The webchat is hosted on a demo website. the web chat in azure is also giving me the same error.

Comment: @hkhan Can you either replicate the issue right now or give me a timestamp of when it last occurred? I'm only showing HTTP status codes of 200 and 201 for the last 7 days, which could mean there's an issue before it hits our servers somewhere. I'll look into this more tomorrow, too.

Comment: it started happening on October 23rd 2019 4:14 pm

Comment: @hkhan See the update in my "answer".

Comment: @hkhan Any luck?

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT none so far. I am working on clients UAT environment which works fine. I will get back to this issue in my environment later. I will update this post if I resolve it.

Comment: @hkhan I was attempting to dig into your issue more, but when chatting with your bot, I get "The subscription is in a disabled state". Did you turn off your Azure subscription?

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT That is it! I just found out that that particular subscription where my dev bot was places has been turned off or whatever. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @hkhan Phew! Glad we got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trial and error, this was the issue:

I was attempting to dig into your issue more, but when chatting with your bot, I get "The subscription is in a disabled state". Did you turn off your Azure subscription?

> I just found out that that particular subscription where my dev bot was places has been turned off or whatever.

---

My first recommendation is that you need to make sure `azure portal > your resource group > your app service > Settings > CORS` looks like this:

[image]

Second, in `azure portal > your resource group > your web app bot > Channels` if you have the DirectLine channel enabled and you're using `Enhanced authentication options`, make sure you have the appropriate client hosts listed.

This is not a common error--at all. Make sure that you deployed the bot following [the Deployment Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

---

Let me know if you still run into trouble. This "answer" was just too long for a comment, but I can edit it if you try these and let me know how it goes.

---

#### Update 1

By any chance are you using Websockets? If so, try disabling them.

I'm not seeing a single error hit the backend, which leads me to believe it may be something on your side. Are you behind a proxy or firewall that might be preventing access?

In `Azure Portal > Your Resource Group > Your App Service > TLS/SSL settings`, do you have TLS 1.2 enabled?

Does Application Insights show any errors? If so, please update your question with them.

[image]

Comment: I am not using any enhanced authentication option for DirectLine. I checked my CORS and they have the origins you shared. I also tested by adding an * to allow everything. The same code base is working perfectly in a different azure client. In my azure the bot does show me the welcome adaptive card. It is just when I try to send a message that i get the errors i shared above.